# what is so special about MongoDB indexing?

Tags: mongodb

I was reading the MongoDB documentation, where it lists Indexing as an special feature. But after reading the doc, I still can't see what it is that makes MongoDB index special. Anyone can explain?

Comment: Can you share the relevant page?

Comment: @Antonis http://docs.mongodb.org/master/MongoDB-indexes-guide.pdf

Comment: Cant find that line, but anyway you might want to check TokuMX which build on Mongo engine and uses Fractal Indexes which are quite interesting.

Comment: What did you expect to be special? :-)

Answer (score -1):

there is absolutely nothing special about it. absolutely zero; nothing.
if you want REALLY advanced indexing -> use PostgreSQL.

Comment: Can you please explain us why PostgreSQL indexing is better that MongoDB? I would easily add a answer like use Oracle or MS SQL Server.

Comment: PostgreSQL has 5 types of indexes: Normal btrees, Gist (for geometric indexing), GIN (for full text), sp-gist (space partitioned gist) and hashes. New index types are being implemented as we speak. The beauty is that PostgreSQL indexes are more of a framework. So, you can teach your index how to behave (this is called an operator class). This is an insanely powerful feature. Imagine you want to index "colors". You cannot easily sort colors. However, you might want to do something like: "give me everything containing red". Example: http://www.cybertec.at/operator-classes-explained/

Comment: One more thing: If those index types are not enough, there is a patch floating around allowing you to implement your own indexing algorithms (bloom filter, some special tree, etc.) on your own pretty easily. Of course, this is only for expert users but the main issue is: You can customize your PostgreSQL indexes excessively. In addition to that the optimizer knows how to deal with this stuff perfectly. It is really very flexible. In fact,it is the most flexible implementation of indexes I am aware of.

Comment: I am not here to support Mongo, it supports text, geo, and hash indexes but all based on btree i think. I will check your last comment is interesting. Remove the -1

Comment: a btree is not suitable for geometric operations. a btree is not able to do "contains" like an rtree would. rtree semantics can be provided via gist indexes in PostgreSQL.

Comment: You should replace the rant in the answer with the information in the comments in a structured form (and receive upvotes instead of downvotes).